# react-beautiful-dnd stop draggable from moving out of div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd, react-beautiful-dnd

I am using a sample code to understand react-beautiful-dnd.
Reference code is https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-cherry-8c1hhl

How can I disallow Draggable to move out of a region? If you look at the picture it is being taken to the header section which is wrong.
[image]